# Publish development version with semantic-release

Tags: javascript, travis-ci, semantic-release

I am using semantic-release with travis CI to automatically publish my package. I have two question:

1. My version has automatically been upgraded to v1.0.0. I want it to be something like v1.0.0-development. How can I do that?
2. Why my github's package.json's version not same as what has been published to npm?

Answer (score 1):

> My version has automatically been upgraded to v1.0.0. I want it to be something like v1.0.0-development. How can I do that?

You can't because `v1.0.0-development` is not a valid semantic version. Once https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/issues/563 is released you will be able to use pre-release version (like `v1.0.0-development.1`).

> Why my github's package.json's version not same as what has been published to npm?

See the first entry in the FAQ: https://semantic-release.gitbook.io/semantic-release/support/faq#why-is-the-package-jsons-version-not-updated-in-my-repository